# indexOf finds empty string

Tags: c#

I got a positive result when ctrl.Text happened to be an empty string (value was 0)

Is that the correct behavior? Do I need to check for an empty string?

```
"Next|Prev|First|Last|Search".IndexOf(ctrl.Text) > -1
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, in the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx) you will find.

> if value is String.Empty, the return value is 0.